# Batch Script to Create Multiple Folders within Multiple Folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory-structure

I'm trying try create a folder structure of multiple folders within another folder.

The below script creates the same subfolders but not what I need.

```bash
@ECHO ON
SET RootDir=C:\Main
SET SubA=A,B
SET SubB=Rates,Docs,Fee,Category,Grades,6000,7,8,Falcon
FOR %%A IN (%SubA%) DO FOR %%B IN (%SubB%) DO IF NOT EXIST "%RootDir%\%%~A\%%~B" MD "%RootDir%\%%~A\%%~B"
EXIT
```

I need suppport to modify the script to create as per required folder structure.

```
 - Main folder
   - A
      - Rates
      - Docs
      - Fee
      - Category
   - B
      - Grades
      - 6000
      - 7
      - 8
      - Falcon
```

Comment: Of course it cannot work! To begin with, your code uses two values under `SubA` which are not required, and your `SubB` values are missing six of the required values. Next, `Sub folder 4` appears in two different parent directories, and your code makes no attempt to account for that. It seems to me as if you have a question which is lacking in sufficient detail, and code which you've made no reasonable attempt to write. Given that this site does not offer a free code writing service, and you have not even shown us the actual results, I strongly advise that you [Edit] your question soon.

Comment: Edited as requested in summary its creating 8 subfolders in folder A and B instead of 4 subfolders in folder A and 4 subfolders in folder b

Comment: You have still not made an attempt to create your required directory structure. We don't provide a tutorial/support service here either. We expect you to write code that attempts the task. Then, if it fails to do that, you provide us with all of the information we need to reproduce the code problem. To reiterate, we help you with an issue with your code, the code you have submitted does not exhibit an issue. Your only issue is that your code does not attempt the task you require of it.

Comment: unfortunatley i am trying the code but failing to create with separate names it create combined subfolders in the folder A and folder b as 8 folders from 1 to 8.

Comment: That is exactly how you coded it.  If you want 5, 6, 7 and 8 to only be under B then you need to have separate variables and two sets of FOR commands.

Comment: Thanks can you emphasize more for two sets of FOR commands

Comment: Do not use `EXIT` at the end of a batch file. That is never necessary and just counterproductive for multiple reasons. Second the batch file needs just two lines: __1.__ `@for %%I in ("1" "2" "3" "4") do @md "C:\Main\A\%%~I" 2>nul` __2.__ `@for %%I in ("5" "6" "7" "8") do @md "C:\Main\B\%%~I" 2>nul` It is really so simple. The command line examples use double quoted folder names in case of the real folder names are not `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` but some other names containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` which require that all folder names without/with path are in `"`.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption here is that you want to create the subfolders dynamically, even if you have more sub folders in `C:\Main`

My other assumption is that the subfolders being numerical here is probably just a use case you gave to simplify the question.

I am posting this answer based on the examples you requested, if your real-world folders will be manually added as an environment variable, then this will not work with the numerical counter.

That is possible by iterating over the subfolders, then running a loop for each sub directory and creating the folders.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "rootdir=C:\Main"
set "subs=A,B"
set "cnt=0"
for %%i in (%subs%) do (
    for /l %%a in (1,1,4) do (
        set /a cnt+=1
        md "%rootdir%\%%i\!cnt!" 2>nul
  )
)
```

This will work even if you have more sub folders, i.e `C`,`D`,`E` because of the `for /l` loop that increments only 4 counts per folder and will keep doing so until it has looped the entire `subs` environment variable.

Comment: Hello yes i want to simply the questions for subfolders and numbered them actually its not numerical its different subfolders i.e Main Folder -> A -> Rates

Comment: @aza01 that is why it is important to post a complete example of your requirments, not irrelevant examples, else we are just wasting each others time.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directories are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

SET "dirs=A B C"
SET "sdirs=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 "extra 1" Stack"

SET /a #d=0,#sd=0
FOR %%e IN (%dirs%) DO SET /a #d+=1&MD "%sourcedir%\%%e" >NUL 2>nul
FOR %%e IN (%sdirs%) DO SET /a #sd+=1
SET /a #sdind=(#sd + #d - 1) / #d

:nextd
FOR %%e IN (%dirs%) DO SET "#dirname=%%~e"&CALL SET "dirs=%%dirs:*%%e=%%"&GOTO gotd
:gotd

SET /a scount=0

:nexts
FOR %%e IN (%sdirs%) DO CALL SET "sdirs=%%sdirs:*%%e=%%"&MD "%sourcedir%\%#dirname%\%%e" >NUL 2>nul&GOTO gots
:gots

SET /a scount+=1
IF NOT DEFINED sdirs GOTO done
IF %scount% geq %#sdind% GOTO nextd
GOTO nexts

:done

DIR /s/b /ad "%sourcedir%"

GOTO :EOF
```

This is aimed at being a general solution. The "subdirectories" could be a list of filenames, for instance and the `md subdirectory` becomes `move file destination`.

Dealing with poison characters, existing directories or files etc. is not considered. There may be no trailing spaces in `sdirs`.

The objective is to make the subdirectories/move the files so that there is an even distribution as far as possible.

Count the directories and files to `#dirs`, `#sdirs`, then calculate the number of elements to move in `#sdind`.

Then grab the first element of the list and remove it from the list in each case, creating/moving as appropriate until the count in `#sdind` is reached, then step on to the next until done.

Comment: Hello, I put numbers to simply my questions for subfolders  actually its with different folder names

Comment: So `SET "dirs=A,B"` and `SET "sdirs=Rates,Docs,Fee,Category,Grades,6000,7,8"` should work for you. It does for me.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, its failing if there addtional subfolders and creating in wrong places. You can tryt by adding any additional folder under "B"

Comment: How is the routine expected to know that you want the first 4 subdirectories under `A` and the remainder under `B`?

Comment: Not necesssay it depends time to time during creation somestimes i can have 4 subdirectories under A and sometimes i can have 7 subdirectories under A or can be else.

Comment: So how does the routine know this? It's not very good at reading minds!

Comment: To have manual line in this case, since number of folders are not fixed

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working for my question. Posted after testing.

```
@ECHO ON
@for %%I in ("Rates" "Docs" "Fee" "Category") do @md "C:\Main\A\%%~I" 2>nul
@for %%I in ("Grades" "6000" "7" "8" "Falcon") do @md "C:\Main\B\%%~I" 2>nul
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**